# Как получить ответ от сервера после отправки файла через cURL Java

Tags: java, curl

подскажите пожалуйста как реализовать следующее. Я сформировал отправку картинки на сервер, следующим образом:

```
package api;

import properties.BaseProperties;

import java.io.IOException;

public class SendToServer {

    public static void sendRequest() {
        String command = "curl -X POST @" + BaseProperties.pictureDir + " https://dev.cp.netgowifi.com/point/marketing/banner-settings/shoko/ --insecure";
        try {
            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

По получению картинки сервер должен вернуть мне сформированный id в виде числа для этой картинки. 
Вопрос - как реализовать получение ответа от сервера и вычленить из него id?

Comment: Не стану писать ответ, слишком просто. Вот ваше [решение](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5711150/9719337)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

у класса `Process` есть метод [getInputStream()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getInputStream--). C помощью него вы можете прочитать полученный стрим, примерно так:

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getOutputStream(), Charset.defaultCharset()))) {
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line).append("\n");
    }
}
System.out.println(sb);
```

ну и дальше уже распарсить ответ, как вам угодно.